# Firestore - Complex queries when deploying to multiple

Tags: android, ios, firebase, web, google-cloud-firestore

My team is developing an Android App, iOS App and Web that will all be doing the exact same thing. 
We are using firestore and I was wondering what people would recommend for our complex queries. Since they will have to be rewritten three different times. iOS, Android and Web.
Should these complex queries happen within the "cloud functions"? Within one HTTPS request for insertions, reading etc? Or have their very own queries for each different environment?

Comment: If you're looking for an open-ended discussion about best practices, it's more appropriate to ask on firebase-talk rather than Stack Overflow.  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebase-talk

Comment: Have you considered creating a Progressive Web App, rather than 3 separate apps?

Comment: Can you clearly define what a *complex query* is? More importantly, whatever queries they are, they will be very similar across platforms as the underlying data is the same. This is way to open ended as well.